# Spatial Anchor not visible in device portal's 3D view

Tags: hololens

I would like to ask whether Spatial Anchors created on application level should be visible in device portal's 3D view? I am creating Spacial Anchor using [SpatialAnchor.TryCreateRelativeTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.spatialanchor.trycreaterelativeto?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Perception_Spatial_SpatialAnchor_TryCreateRelativeTo_Windows_Perception_Spatial_SpatialCoordinateSystem_) - it seems to work as expected, but I don't see any anchor created this way inside of 3D view. I see there anchors created by system itself (for example placed on positions of windows), but not the ones I create in application. Thanks.

Comment: As a reminder, the anchor will not be automatically updated in the 3D view, therefore it needs to select Update to display or update the spatial anchors for the active app.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this and was therefore hitting Update after I created Spatial Anchor in application. This however didn't display my anchors in 3D view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpatialAnchor::TryCreateRelativeTo() anchors are temporary/tied to the app instance, so not visible to the 3d view in the portal.

You will need to save the anchor to the store for it to show up in the portal. Otherwise, it's a temporary anchor for the lifetime of the application. For more information, please refer to: [SpatialAnchorStore.TrySave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.spatialanchorstore.trysave?view=winrt-20348)

Comment: Aha, that makes perfect sense. Thank you very much.